# explicit instantiation declaration of template class field

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clang++

I have such `test.hpp`:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <map>

template <typename T, typename Tag>
struct Boo {
  using ElementType = T;
  static const char name[];
};

struct CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1 {};
using Pref1 = Boo<int, CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1>;

struct Foo {
  template <typename CfgElm>
  void get() const {
    auto it = cache_.find(CfgElm::name);
    assert(it != cache_.end());
  }
  Foo();

private:
  struct CmpCStr final {
    bool operator()(const char *a, const char *b) const {
      return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }
  };

  using PrefCacheMap = std::map<const char *, int, CmpCStr>;
  PrefCacheMap cache_;
};
```

and use it like this (`test2.cpp`):

```
#include "test.hpp"

void f()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.get<Pref1>();
}
```

and initialize it like this (`test.cpp`):

```
#include "test.hpp"

template <> const char Pref1::name[] = "Pref1";

Foo::Foo()
{
    cache_.insert(std::make_pair(Pref1::name, 17));
}
```

This is reduced example, so `Foo::get` do nothing.

clang produces such warning for this code:

```
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 test.cpp test2.cpp
In file included from test2.cpp:1:
./test.hpp:15:35: warning: instantiation of variable 'Boo<int,
      CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1>::name' required here, but no definition is
      available [-Wundefined-var-template]
    auto it = cache_.find(CfgElm::name);
                                  ^
test2.cpp:6:6: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'Foo::get<Boo<int, CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1> >' requested here
        foo.get<Pref1>();
            ^
./test.hpp:7:21: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
  static const char name[];
                    ^
./test.hpp:15:35: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to
      suppress this warning if 'Boo<int, CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1>::name' is
      explicitly instantiated in another translation unit
    auto it = cache_.find(CfgElm::name);
```

This codes does compiles and links without problems.
The only problem is warning.
I have no idea how to suppress it.

I found this question [explicit instantiation of static variable of a template class in different translation units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670775/explicit-instantiation-of-static-variable-of-a-template-class-in-different-trans) , but I can not use provided solution, because of I don't know template arguments.

I can not write: `template<> int Boo<Type1, Type2>::name;`
because of the whole idea is to use my code like this: `foo.get<Pref1>()`, without explicitly pointing that `Pref1` is  `Boo<int, CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1>`.

So anybody know how to suppress warning, without turn of such warning for whole project via `-Wno-undefined-var-template`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `Boo::name` template definition in the same header file:

```
   static const char * name;
}; // End Boo 

template<typename T, typename Tag> 
const char * Boo<T, Tag>::name{};
```

Update: now it is clarified that you are trying to write specialization for `name` in some translation unit *after* instantiating it in header file. This will require some trickery. You need to declare specialization in header file *before* instantiating it and probably use external template and explicitly instantiate it in the same translation unit as `name`:

```
// header

template <typename T, typename Tag> struct Boo {
  using ElementType = T;
  static const char * name;
};

struct CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1 {};

// indicate that name for this specialization exists elsewhere
template<> const char * Boo<int, CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1>::name;

// indicate that template is defined somewhere
extern template struct Boo<int, CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1>;

using Pref1 = Boo<int, CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1>;

// test.cpp

// definition will be present only in this translation unit
template<> const char * Boo<int, CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1>::name{"Pref1"};

// explicit instantiation
template struct Boo<int, CFG_ELM_NAME__Pref1>;
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vcHcLWn3EJwNUOgK)

Comment: It works, but I had to remove `*` and add `[]{}` to make it compiles without errors. But what means `{}` at the end, initialization? But I init `name` in other `.cpp` not show in my question.

Comment: @user1244932 `{}` at the end is a [direct list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Initializing `name` in `.cpp` is not a good idea, see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: I do not initialize whole template in cpp, I intialize concrete type, like this `template <> const char Pref1::name[] = "Pref1";`

Comment: I 've updated my question to show how I initialize `name`. I tried your solution and it works fine with `clang++`, but `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 test.cpp test2.cpp` return `multiple definition of name` during link time, but compiles fine without `template<typename T, typename Tag> 
const char * Boo<T, Tag>::name{};` I used clang 5.0.1 and gcc 7.2.1.